# Search max and compare with other min in SQL

Tags: mysql, max, min

Okay so I have a table in Mysql server with seller reviews:

```
SellerReview (ID, User_ID, Time, Review, Seller_id)
```

and another table where the `Seller_id`'s are coupled with a name Users (ID, name).

Now do I have to make a query so that tuples (V1, V2) are selected where the max review of V2 is strictly less than the min review of V1.

What I have is:

```
SELECT U1.name AS V1, U2.naam AS V2
FROM Users AS U1, Users AS U2, SellerReview AS S1, SellerReview AS S2
WHERE U1.id = S1.seller_id   
  AND G2.id = V2.seller_id 
  AND ((SELECT MAX(S.Review) 
        FROM SellerReview AS S 
        WHERE S.Seller_id = U1.id) > (SELECT MIN(S.review) 
                                      FROM SellerReview AS S 
                                      WHERE S.Seller_id = G2.id))
```

But I don't get the right table. Does anyone know the problem or anyone who could help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2):

To get all pair of reviewers without duplication, join on `U2.id < U1.id`. From there you can use `having` to make sure the max review of the first user is less than the min review of the other user.

```
SELECT U1.name AS V1, U2.name AS V2
FROM Users AS U1
JOIN SellerReview AS S1 on U1.id = S1.seller_id
JOIN Users AS U2 ON U2.id < U1.id
JOIN SellerReview S2 on U2.id = S2.seller_id
GROUP BY U1.name, U2.name
HAVING MAX(S2.review) < MIN(S1.review)
```

This query assumes that `Users.name` is unique. If it's not, you should group by `Users.id` instead and join back to the Users table to get the name.